# Problems with Emmet

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm having troubles with my Emmet module in VS Code. The problem occurs when I'm trying to declare an array in JS using array literals. Every time I close the brackets, on the last one, Emmet pops up and suggests some wild stuff I've never seen, written or encountered in any matter before. It looks like this:

```
> "Emmet Abbreviation

<div 5,="|" 30,="|" 50="|">|</div>"
```

See the screenshot, please.

It tries to paste this in my code and does so on "Tab" keypress. I don't know where this has come from and was unable to fix it. This bug is so annoying.

Any suggestions on how to get around with this and why it has become so at all?

**EDITED: Thank you all for answers, but let me be a bit more concrete what I'm asking about: what's causing this and how to revert my VS Code back to the way it was just 2 days ago? There was no such a problem back then. Also there's no such problem on my second PC, but porting and replacing config files didn't solve my problem.

[image: Problem with Emmet]

VS Code info

Version: 1.63.2 (user setup)
Date: 2021-12-15T09:40:02.816Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043

I have only 5 extensions installed:

ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets v4.1.0
Live Sass Compiler v3.0.0
Live Server v5.7.4
Prettier - Code formatter v9.1.0
Monokai Charcoal Full Dark v0.0.4

Two or three months ago I've configured my textmate scopes to add more differentiations to colors and fonts of my tags and JS stuff. That's the only thing I've configured manually, and it wasn't the cause of my current issue. I code almost every day, and it was ok during that period. I didn't update or install anything related to VS Code recently, i.e. in 2022.

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript question. Please remove javascript tag.

Comment: It happens only when I'm writing JS code. It's not about language itself, of course, but it's directly related.

Answer (score 0):

simply type the brackets and items first:

```
[5, 30, 50]
```

then type the name and identifier:

```
const someArr = [5, 30, 50]
```

I know this is annoying but have not found another way.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But that's not the case. I can just ctrl-z that insertion and it works. But the problem occurred recently, 2 days ago it was just fine, no issues at all. What I'm asking is how to have it back the way it was.

Comment: It looks like that's HTML, so your language settings might be screwed up.

Comment: anyways, we need more information to fix this.

Comment: Didn't touch those, actually, and no one did, I'm the only user of this PC.

Comment: Edit your post to include more information such as updates, version, Emmet version, activity on your PC, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Added additional info. as much as I could.